# VMware Workstation 16.2.4 Pro: Some keys are not sent to the virtual machine, whatever operating system it has

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-22.04

VMware® Workstation 16 Pro 16.2.4 build-20089737
Host machine: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Upgraded from 20.04 LTS).
Virtual machine: any.

The Windows-Logo key, the ctrl+alr+del keys, the stamp-r-sist key (for the screenshots) and I don't know what others are not sent to the virtual machine, **even if it has focus and is full screen.**
The host machine reacts to pressing those keys but not the VM.
This problem arose after upgrading the host system from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Why? How do I resolve?
I tried reinstalling VMware from 0 but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using wayland or xorg ?

Comment: Downgrading to VMware v16.2.3 doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: How stupid I am, after the upgrade to 22.04 Wayland put on, bringing him back to Xorg I solved the problem. XD @harrymc Put it as an answer so I can mark it as the best answer.

Comment: It's already in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using wayland, then there have been reports that this might work
better in xorg.

The post
[Using Ctrl+Alt+F1 in a VMWare Virtual Machine](https://electrictoolbox.com/vmware-ctrl-alt-f1/)
has this advice:

> discovered that in order to send a regular Ctrl+Alt keyboard combination to the guest you need to press Ctrl+Alt+Space, then release the spacebar while still holding down the Ctrl+Alt keys, and then pressing the extra key. So to drop to a console I needed to Ctrl+Alt+Space, release the space, keep holding down Ctrl+Alt and then press the F1 key.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Solved, Wayland is the problem.

Comment: Xorg works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup here:  Windows 11 Pro Host, VMware Workstation V16 newest, Ubuntu 22.04 and other machines too.

Windows keystrokes are not sent from Host to Guest as you describe.

If you need to use the Windows and other keys in Ubuntu, you need to define in the Ubuntu guest. That is completely normal use of keystrokes.

View the guest as a different real machine.  You do not send keystrokes from one real machine to another real machine.

Comment: My host is Ubuntu 22.04, my guest is Windows or Linux does not matter, the result is the same.

Comment: Yes same thing.  See my comment about real machines.

Comment: `Windows 11 Pro Host`. The `host` is the real machine, your real machine is `Windows 11 Pro`, my real machine is `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`.

Comment: It does not matter which machine is real or guest, but generally keystrokes won’t be sent between machines (or you need a very specialized app)

Comment: That's true and I don't know if this thing is caused by the latest version of VMware

Comment: `If you need to use the Windows and other keys in Ubuntu, you need to define in the Ubuntu guest. That is completely normal use of keystrokes.`
Where do I define them? I couldn't find this thing in the settings.

Comment: You would have to look in your Ubuntu settings. I confess that I do not need to do this.

Comment: `View the guest as a different real machine. You do not send keystrokes from one real machine to another real machine.` What do you mean?

Comment: Downgrading to VMware v16.2.3 doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Keystrokes generally cannot be set between machines so what you want is not possible as I have posted.

Comment: How stupid I am, after the upgrade to 22.04 Wayland put on, bringing him back to Xorg I solved the problem. XD